# Can I use robots.txt to disallow e-mail adresses?

Tags: html, robots.txt

In the footer of my website I have this e-mail adress that goes to info@mydomain. I want to know if it's possible for me to disallow bad/good robots to index this adress?

Thank you

Comment: If the idea is to disallow bad robots, will they obey *robots.txt* considering that they are bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. If the page is allowed to be indexable, the email will be gobbled up too.

However, you could take steps to make sure the bots don't see it. If it's not essential that they see it immediately you could use a [CAPTCHA to protect it](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/)

Or you could simply use the image of the text representation.

You could also go the [JS route to hiding it](http://joemaller.com/js-mailer.shtml). Basically allow the email to be seen via with only JS

Comment: I simply changed the info@mydomain.com into the javascript code found on joemaller.com/js-mailer.shtml, this fixed it all and it looks exactly the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's not. If it's on the internet, they can get it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature of robots.txt, its intended feature is to stop Google from crawling certain paths.  You can instead block emails in this sort of way (the easy way):

```
    webmaster (at) website (dot) com
```

It's still visible to a human, but blocks some spam / search / crawlers / bots from using it.  The best way really is to use gd2 to make a small image with a string of the email, and show that.  A human can read it and write it down in their mail program, but a bot generally should not.  You will still have some bots that can.

Comment: Google is no the only company that operates bots … and robots.txt predates the existence of Google by about three years.

Comment: Humans can only read images if they can see. Don't discriminate against people with vision related handicaps. You'll also create problems for dyslexics by forcing them to manually transcribe text from an image.

Comment: @David Google is one of the few search bots that properly respects robots.txt, as well: you can combine this with the javaScript route (mentioned below) to have a "click-to-copy" image.

Comment: Most search bots respect robots.txt. The prime violators of it are spambots.

Comment: @David How can you say that when search engines like Bing refuse to stop indexing or crawling something in robots.txt, if it had already started; or if it didn't care to stop.  I've seen the same thing happen with the Chinese search (forgot the name), and Yahoo Slurp! as well.